# How to print stuff to stdout with RIO library

Tags: haskell

How do people print stuff out to stdout when using the RIO library?

I've read the discussion on the RIO github discussing:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/rio/issues/5#issuecomment-355061756

But couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way is to use the [logging functions](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.13/rio-0.1.12.0/RIO.html#g:8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.19 script
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import RIO

main :: IO ()
main = runSimpleApp $ do logInfo "Hello World"
```

And on executing them:

```
$ stack rio.hs
Hello World
```

You can also use the [logOptionsHandle](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.13/rio-0.1.12.0/RIO.html#v:logOptionsHandle) to pass any type of `Handle` to it (including `stdout` or a file handle if you want the logging on a file) and configure accordingly. You can even use the Prelude's `print` if you want, but unlike logging approach above this is not as efficient and is not thread safe, which means it can result in interleaved output in a concurrent setting:

```
import Prelude (print)
import RIO

main :: IO ()
main = runSimpleApp $ do liftIO $ print "hello"
```

There is more [detailed documentation on rio here](https://tech.fpcomplete.com/haskell/library/rio).

Comment: Thanks! BTW: Do I have to put import RIO in every module file?

Comment: @McBearHolden Yes, you would need to import it to the functions in it.